# Python 3.X pulling too many ip addresses when trying to read file

Tags: python, python-3.x, nmap

I have a scan report from Nmap. I'm trying to get the information that only pertains to the certain IP address. I'm trying pull the IP address for this part of the code I will work on the next piece later. I think it has something to do with the `\n` character at the end of the IP address. I need the code to say I want this IP address and this IP address alone. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#Python3.X 
target_ip = "10.10.100.1"


fhand = open('ScanTest.txt','r')
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('Nmap scan report for')and (target_ip):
        print(line)
```

My results end up being

```
Nmap scan report for 10.10.100.1
Nmap scan report for 10.10.100.2
Nmap scan report for 10.10.100.100
Nmap scan report for 10.10.100.101
Nmap scan report for 10.10.100.103
Nmap scan report for 10.10.100.102
```

Comment: Both [python-3.x] and [nmap] tags are superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code matched too much because a non empty string is always `True`, so your code printed *all* the lines beginning with `"Nmap..."`.

How can you write correctly the test after `and` ? You used the string method `startswith`, but there is also `endswith`...

I also took the liberty of moving the constant requested beginning out of the loop,

```
target_ip = "10.10.100.1"
begins = "Nmap scan report for"

fhand = open('ScanTest.txt','r')
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith(begins) and line.endswith(target_ip):
        print(line)
```

---

Judging from the output you have posted, the `startswith` and the `endswith` imply that the line is exactly equal to `"Nmap scan report for 10.10.100.1`"...

It could be more interesting *to count* how many fixed lines are present in the file (what follows is idiomatic Python to count the number of matches, it works because the arithmetic value of a non-match is `0` and of a match is `1`)

```
 count = sum(line==target_line for line in fhand)
```

or maybe it's interesting to have also the position in the file

```
 count = 0
 for n, line in enumerate(fhand):
     if line==target_line:
         print("%8d %s"%(n, line))
         count = count+1
 print(n, "matches found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the line …

```
if line.startswith('Nmap scan report for')and (target_ip):
```

… to …

```
if line.startswith('Nmap scan report for') and (line.split(' ')[4] == target_ip):
```